# Vertical align checkbox / label pairs

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, cross-platform, vertical-alignment

I go through the posts on this issue on Stack Overflow, but nothing really works for me. I have the following CSS code to vertically align checkbox / label pair:

```
body {
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

fieldset {
    line-height: 100%;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

The full HTML code is [here](http://821.gvs.arnes.si/test/index.html).

Checkbox / label pairs are vertically centered correctly in Safari (5.0.3) and Firefox (3.6.13) under Mac OS X. On Chrome (Mac OS X) checkboxes are rendered slightly to the top. On Windows OS checkboxes and associate labels are aligned to the bottom (consistently across different browsers: Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and Internet Explorer 8).

Could somebody please explain me why this differences between browsers / OS happens (and also how to avoid them)?

**Update**

The hack to vertically align checkbox with label in Chrome under Mac is as follows:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Now need to implement OS and browser specific conditionals...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No idea why the browsers do different things, they just always do. As far as this, did you try `display:table-cell;`?

Comment: Try giving the checkboxes top padding which will decrease their height a little to center them.

Comment: This doesn't help anyone without specific reference to the original code and question. Adding `display: table-cell` to what?!?!

Answer (score 14):

another solution:

```
.checkbox{
vertical-align:-3px;
}
```

note: it's simple. But not always works fine if the font-size of label is too big.

Comment: To make the adjustment sensitive to font-size, you could use `em` instead of `px`, e.g. `vertical-align:-0.1em`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the default margins/padding on the `<input>` are messing things up?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I finally did it:

```
label input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" />
<style>
.GlobalEntityComboBox {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 190px;
}
.GlobalEntityComboBox li {
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.GlobalEntityComboBox li.checked {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border-top: 1px solid green;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.GlobalEntityComboBox input {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.GlobalEntityComboBox span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="GlobalEntityComboBox">
    <li class="checked"><input type="checkbox" checked/><span>All Servers</span></li>
    <li class="checked"><input type="checkbox" checked/><span>Server 1</span></li>
    <li class="checked"><input type="checkbox" checked/><span>Server 2</span></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>Server 3</span></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.flcheck-wrapper
{ overflow:hidden;
  margin:5px 0;
}

.flcheck-wrapper p
{ font-size:12px;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  line-height:20px;
  margin:0 0 0 10px;
}

.flcheck-wrapper input[type="checkbox"],
.flcheck-wrapper input[type="radio"]
{ display:inline;
  float:left;
  margin:0 !imortant;
  line-height:20px;
  height:20px;
}

<div class="flcheck-wrapper">    
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="true" checked="checked" />
    <p>Some kind of text</p>
</div>
<div class="flcheck-wrapper">    
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="false" />
    <p>Some kind of text</p>
</div>
```